# Concurrent Multipath Transfer over SCTP

Tags: networking, server, sockets

I'm trying to run Concurrent Multipath Transfer over SCTP.

I have two machines running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS, and they have `lksctp-tools 1.0.11+dfsg-1` installed

Does this version support CMT? if yes what is the flag in `setsockopt` function